# How to edit saved text in tinymce or other wysiwyg?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm trying to understand how it is possible to obtain the content that I keep in the tinymce editor, then be able to edit. I try the basics in terms of code, saving information, and it displays correctly on other pages, but I can not edit what I saved from the iframe.

Here is the code that I currently use:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // Opciones generales
    mode : "textarea_especifico",
    editor_selector : "mceEditor"
});

console.debug(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());

tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});

tinyMCE.get('textarea_especifico').getContent();
```

I'm currently using the 4.3 version of tinymce. If anyone knows how to do what I ask in another wysiwyg can also place the way they did to guide me.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you try to give a better explanation ? what do you mean by " when you reenter the data" ?

Comment: I try to keep the text in the iframe I saved the first time, so you can edit at any time, I explain?

Answer (score 0):

"I try to keep the text in the iframe I saved the first time, so you can edit at any time"

To achieve this, you will, obviously need to store your data somewhere.
This can be in cookies, local file, server file, database.
Each of these way has pros and cons.

Worst, some of these storage can only be accessible via a server-side langage, like PHP, to handle server files or database connection. They are (sadly for you) the most reliable places to store data, so, for common projects, you should go this way.

As the very most common way of storing data is database, specifically SQL, I suggest you to consider learning basics of PHP/Mysql.

Comment: It's possible with asp.net and sql?

Comment: ok, i have done this with a normal textarea, so, i believe the problem comes from the wysiwyg, because convert the textarea to  an iframe.

Comment: Where did you save you data when working with textarea ?

Comment: it's some hard to explain, but basically i save the data in a sql varchar

Comment: Ok. What langage do you use to connect the database  (as sql is a database) for saving your text ?